# looping in xslt using xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

i want to loop through a xml file all the values are displayed while looping except //Script2[@time] it is in different position so i directly selected like that and for some reason i dont know //Script2[@time] is not displaying any value

```
 <table class="table_styling3">
 <tr><th>Name</th><th>Duration</th><th>Errors</th><th>Actions</th><th>Verifications</th>  <th>Traces</th></tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="Report/Scripts/Script1">
 <tr>
 <td widht="20%"><xsl:value-of select="@File"/></td>
 <td widht="20%"><xsl:value-of select="//Script2[@time]"/></td>
 <td width="10%"><xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Error'])"/></td>
 <td width="10%"><xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Action'])"/></td>
 <td width="10%"><xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Verification'])"/></td>
 <td width="10%"><xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Trace'])"/></td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
```

My xml file goes here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Report App="RIATest" Version="4.7"   Project="D:\Projects\Automation\RIATest\Nomura\Nomura.rtp">
  <Startup>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:38.578" Type="Info" Message="Launching iexplore.exe &quot;http://mobiuss-dev.operasolutions.com:8080/nomura-test/&quot;"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:38.625" Type="Info" Message="Application launched (process id=4108)."/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:38.625" Type="Info" Message="Waiting for connection from agent..."/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.453" Type="Info" Message="Agent connection accepted. Application id=nomura-ui, index=0"/>
  </Startup>
  <Scripts>
  <Script1 File="Login.rts" Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.468">
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.531" Type="Verification" Line="8" Col="58"   Message="Verification passed: SparkApplication(&quot;nomura-ui&quot;)=&gt;visible is equal  to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.578" Type="Verification" Line="10" Col="50" Message="Verification passed: FlexForm(&quot;loginForm&quot;)=&gt;visible is equal to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.625" Type="Verification" Line="12" Col="65" Message="Verification passed: FlexLabel(&quot;Username::Username:&quot;)=&gt;text is equal to &quot;Username:&quot;"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.656" Type="Verification" Line="14" Col="65" Message="Verification passed: FlexLabel(&quot;Password::Password:&quot;)=&gt;text is equal to &quot;Password:&quot;"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.671" Type="Verification" Line="17" Col="39" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;label is equal to &quot;Log In&quot;"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.703" Type="Verification" Line="18" Col="35" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;enabled is equal to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.718" Type="Verification" Line="19" Col="35" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;visible is equal to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.734" Type="Verification" Line="22" Col="35" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;enabled is equal to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.750" Type="Verification" Line="23" Col="54" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;label is equal to &quot;Forgot your password?&quot;"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.765" Type="Verification" Line="24" Col="36" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;selected is equal to false"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.781" Type="Verification" Line="25" Col="35" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;visible is equal to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.796" Type="Verification" Line="28" Col="61" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;text is equal to &quot;CORPORATE BOND SPREAD SIGNAL&quot;"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.812" Type="Verification" Line="29" Col="35" Message="Verification passed: comp=&gt;visible is equal to true"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:46.906" Type="Action" Line="32" Col="64" Message="SparkTextInput(&quot;Username::userName&quot;)=&gt;textSelectionChange(0,0)"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:47.000" Type="Action" Line="33" Col="63" Message="SparkTextInput(&quot;Username::userName&quot;)=&gt;textInput(&quot;arun.sekar&quot;)"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:47.031" Type="Action" Line="35" Col="61" Message="SparkTextInput(&quot;Password::password&quot;)=&gt;textInput(&quot;opera100&quot;)"/>
  <Message Time="2012-08-30 15:32:47.093" Type="Action" Line="36" Col="32" Message="SparkButton(&quot;Log In&quot;)=&gt;click()"/>
  </Script>
  </Scripts>
  <Results>
  <Summary scripts="2" time="8.515" errors="2"/>
  <Script2 name="Login.rts" time="0.625" errors="0"/>
  <Script2 name="NOM_0002.rts" time="50.000" errors="2" message="Verification failed: comp=&gt;selected is not equal to expected value true, it is actually equal to false"/>
  </Results>
  </Report>
```

Insted of showing the time 0.625 in the first row and in the second row 50.000 it is displaying empty rows in the table and all other values are displayed as expected.

Comment: Yes, we will need to see your Xml file, as well as the actual and the expected output.

Comment: Where? I can just see "My xml file goes here".

Comment: Ah, now it's there. So, what about actual and expected results?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Cannot chat because in my office they disabled chat please respond over here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently doing this in your XSLT.....

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Script2[@time]"/>
```

However, this will get the text value of the first **Script2** tag which happens to have a **@time@** attribute. I think you actually want to get the value of this **@time** attribute. In this case, do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Script2/@time"/>
```

But, from looking at your XSLT, it is possible you want to get the the **Script2** tag which happens to have the same **@name** as the **@File** attribute of the **Script1** tag.

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Script2[@name=current()/@File]/@time"/>
```

Try this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table class="table_styling3">
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Errors</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Verifications</th>
            <th>Traces</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="Report/Scripts/Script1">
            <tr>
               <td width="20%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@File"/>
               </td>
               <td width="20%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//Script2[@name=current()/@File]/@time"/>
               </td>
               <td width="10%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Error'])"/>
               </td>
               <td width="10%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Action'])"/>
               </td>
               <td width="10%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Verification'])"/>
               </td>
               <td width="10%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Trace'])"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table class="table_styling3">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Duration</th>
<th>Errors</th>
<th>Actions</th>
<th>Verifications</th>
<th>Traces</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">Login.rts</td>
<td width="20%">0.625</td>
<td width="10%">0</td>
<td width="10%">4</td>
<td width="10%">13</td>
<td width="10%">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Actually, it would be more efficient to use an **xsl:key** here to look up the **script2** elements

```
<xsl:key name="script" match="Script2" use="@name"/>
```

Try this XSLT instead. Notice I ahave also replaced the **xsl:for-each** with **xsl:apply-templates** which is often more in the 'spirit' of XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="script" match="Script2" use="@name"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table class="table_styling3">
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Errors</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Verifications</th>
            <th>Traces</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Scripts/Script1"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Script1">
      <tr>
         <td width="20%">
            <xsl:value-of select="@File"/>
         </td>
         <td width="20%">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('script',@File)/@time"/>
         </td>
         <td width="10%">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Error'])"/>
         </td>
         <td width="10%">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Action'])"/>
         </td>
         <td width="10%">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Verification'])"/>
         </td>
         <td width="10%">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Message[@Type='Trace'])"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent Answer exactly what iam looking for, thanks @Tim C ,Thanks for stopping by and spending your time in understanding my query and solving it efficiently. Thank you once again :)